# Gradle 2.2.0 execution failed: SymbolForDebug

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

After upgrading gradle of my project (and library attached to it) from 2.1.3 -> 2.2.0 it doesn't build anymore and it says:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformNative_libsWithStripDebugSymbolForDebug'.
>   java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

Anyone have a clue on why this is?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=223162 cleaning might help

Comment: Thank you, will try that, didn't find this issue listed there

Comment: Happened to me after downgrading SDK target from 24 to 23

Comment: Cleaning didn't work :/ I cannot remove NDK from my project.

I didn't change that setting, I have target SDK on 22. When I revert Gradle back it works but not if I update it.
The problem has to be something with C++ libraries (I think), because Android studio asked on the update something about C++ libraries added(or you couldn't build project)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error:Execution failed for task ':hello\_motion\_tracking:transformNative\_libsWithStripDebugSymbolForDebug'. >](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39761895/errorexecution-failed-for-task-hello-motion-trackingtransformnative-libswith)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40117446/1088975

The point is to set both targetSdkVersion and compileSdkVersion to 22"

Comment: Mine is set to the correct version for all build.gradle files, project structure and flavors for my libGDX project. No juice.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the following lines in build.gradle file:

```
    android {
        // SDK 24 worked for me - make sure you have the latest and update it accordingly.
        compileSdkVersion 24
        buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
    ...
    }
```

Comment: I have compileSdkVersion on 16 because I need to have it. I changed from 22 build tools to your 24.0.2 but it didn't work :/ same issue

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can update the ndk version.
I update the ndk version from r10 to r13,and finally it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check if the location of your NDK folder has any white space in it...if it has you can move your `ndk folder` to the `c:\` drive and rebuild

Also, check the gradle versiom of your app and either upgrade or download later version, because some ndk versions do not support later gradle version